# displaying the particular <div> when i click n a button in while loop

Tags: php

i used a while loop,inside that loop i took a  and a button.when i click on that button display only one  with that button.
Here is my code--

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js1/jquery-2.2.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".bb").each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(){
        $('.aa').each(function(){
            $('.aa').toggle("fast");
            }); 
        });
    });
  });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
 $c = 0;
 while($c <10)
 {
 $c++;?>
 <button class="bb" >x</button>

 <div class="aa" style="display:none;"><input type="text" value="<?php echo $c;?> " class="t1" />
  </div>
<?php }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understand is you want to toggle anchor that is right after the clicked button. If yes, your jQuery should be something like this

```
$(".bb").click(function() {
   $(this).nextAll(".aa").first().css("display", "block");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

It will only display div whose button is clicked, and hide others.

```
    $(".bb").click(function() {
       $(".aa").hide() // hide all div
       $(this).next(".aa").css("display", "block"); // it will display only one div whose previous button is clicked
    });
```